# How to tell cmake to look in /usr/local/zlib/lib instead of /usr/lib?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to compile apitrace, however, when I run cmake, I got the following message

```
-- Could NOT find ZLIB: Found unsuitable version "1.2.5", but required
   is at least "1.2.6" (found /usr/lib/libz.dylib)
```

I have installed the most recent version of zlib in `/usr/local/zlib`, how can I tell cmake to look for it in that path? I already tried with `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/zlib/` but it didn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, I clear the build directory and then use the prefix path and it found the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I erased all the files within the build directory and then run again cmake with the variable `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` set to where zlib was and it found it.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually also set a variable like ZLIB_DIR to your preferred dependency location. The exact variable name depends on the definition in FindZLIB.cmake but you should usually find a corresponding variable using the cmake gui, e.g. `ccmake`.

Setting the [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) you specify where `Find_XXX()` macros will search for your dependencies.

Removing the build dir shouldn't be necessary. It's only required when cmake already successfully found a dependency and you want to find it a different one. However, in this case it suffices to remove `CMackeCache.txt`.